# base transformation

Tags: vector-spaces, transformation

Is there a smart way to make a base transformation matrix for one base to another?

Here are my bases:

$$ E_1= \begin{bmatrix}-0.4656 &  -0.7461  &  0.4760\\
0.8073  & -0.1377 &   0.5738 \\
-0.3626  &  0.6515 &   0.6664
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$E_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.4770  & -0.7463  &  0.4642\\
0.8064  & -0.1616  &  0.5689\\
-0.3496  &  0.6457  &  0.6789
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of $E_1$ as the matrix that transforms the standard basis to the basis $\mathcal B_1$, and similarly for $E_2$. To get from $\mathcal B_1$ to $\mathcal B_2$, go from $\mathcal B_1$ to the standard basis and then from the standard basis to $\mathcal B_2$. So this is the matrix product $E_2E_1^{-1}$.